# Validaciones angular ionic no funcionan la primera vez que ejecuto la aplicación

Tags: angular, firebase, formularios, ionic, validación

Tengo problemas utilizando formularios, para una integración con autenticación de firebase, solicitando usuario y contraseña para habilitar el boton de login, al realizar las validaciones no funcionan, si la aplicación acaba de ser desplegada.
Debo refrescar la aplicación o ir a otra pagina y luego volver para que se habiliten las validaciones, de lo contrario permanecen en estado invalido

Este es mi login.html

```
<form [formGroup]="login" (ngSubmit)="loginFunction()">
    <ion-list>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input formControlName="user" type="text" placeholder="user"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div class="validation-errors">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.user">
          <div class="error-message"
            *ngIf="login.get('user').hasError(validation.type) && (login.get('user').dirty || login.get('user').touched)">
            {{ validation.message }}
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-input formControlName="password" type="password" placeholder="Password"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <div class="validation-errors">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of validation_messages.password">
          <div class="error-message"
            *ngIf="login.get('password').hasError(validation.type) && (login.get('password').dirty || login.get('password').touched)">
            {{ validation.message }}
          </div>
        </ng-container>
      </div>
    </ion-list>
    <div padding>
      <ion-button type="submit" [disabled]="!login.valid">LogIn</ion-button>
    </div>
  </form>
```

Este es mi login.ts

```js
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/auth';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-login',
  templateUrl: 'login.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['login.page.scss'],
})
export class LoginPage {

  login: FormGroup;
  constructor(
    public afAuth: AngularFireAuth, 
    public formBuilder: FormBuilder
  ) {
    this.login = this.createForm();
  }

  private createForm() {
    return this.formBuilder.group({
      user: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\\.[a-z]{2,}$')]],
      password: ['', Validators.required]
    });
  }

  loginFunction() {
    var email = this.login.get('user').value;
    var password = this.login.get('password').value;
    const res = this.afAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function (error) {
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var message= error.message;
      console.log(errorCode);
      console.log(message);
    });
  }

  validation_messages = {
    'user': [
      { type: 'pattern', message: 'User format is incorrect.' },
      { type: 'required', message: 'User is required.' }
    ],
    'password': [
      { type: 'required', message: 'Password is required.' }
    ]
  };
}
```

Realmente las validaciones funcionan, pero no la primera vez que se ejecuta la aplicación.
Adjunto imágenes de la situación.angula

[image: Imagen de la validación al iniciar]

[image: Así lucen las validaciones después de refrescar]

Comment: ¿Ves algún error o mensaje en la consola de JavaScript?

Comment: No, el funcionamiento es normal, la consola no arroja errores, tampoco se muestran los mensajes de fallos de validación, los mensajes y la habilitación del botón solo funcionan luego de refrescar o usar alguna otra funcionalidad de mi aplicación, de primera entrada no funciona.

Comment: pudiste dar con la solución? me pasa lo mismo

Comment: Si, en mi app.component.ts he agregado NgZone
import { Component, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
y he realizado el llamado a mi pagina login con este comando
 this.ngZone.run(() => this.router.navigate(["/login"]));
Esto ha solucionado el error